# Is a c-style string containing only one char considered a string?

Tags: c++

Is a c-style string containing only one char considered a string or would you call that construct a char?

Comment: it is indeed considered as a string, with one element at the index "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero or more characters followed by a NUL-terminator is a C-style string. You can use the double quotation character notation to define a literal.

In C, an `int` that can fit into a `char`, such as '`3'` is a `char`.

Something like `'34'` is  *multicharacter literal*.

Comment: So as long as there is a terminating null-character, it is a C-style string?

Comment: @step: Yes, that's another way of putting it.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks! But so if I have this `char seq[20];` - what would you call this then? Simply an array of characters? If so, isn't it a little confusing since c-style strings are also, in fact, arrays of charterers. Thus, if you would not call `seq` a c-style string, there would not really be a way to imply that it is NOT a c-style string without stating it explicitly.

Comment: @step: I'd call that a load of uninitialised data. Pass that directly to something like strlen and the compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: Finally, so there CANNOT be any strings without the null-character?

Comment: Again, not in the sense that the C standard library string functions expect strings.

Answer (score 1):

A one element buffer is still technically a buffer. Forming a pointer to the start of it is not at all affected by how many items are in it.

So no, it's not a `char`. Furthermore, even the type system would differentiate `char[1]` from `char`.

It's also worth nothing that you may be surprised by what is a 1 character string. Because this one `"a"` has two characters in the buffer, not one. The only one character buffer that is a valid C-string is the empty string.

Comment: and how to define an empty string?

Comment: My is that it is empty if the length of the string is 0. But when would this ever be possible when a string if anything with a terminating null-character? I mean, the null-character increases the length by one

Comment: @step - Being a "C-string" is a property of the data in the buffer. You can have character buffers that are not strings at all. The nul terminator is part of the data representation. That's the distinction you need to make. So a 1 char buffer is only a string if that char is a nul terminator. Coincidentally it's the empty (or 0 length) string.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a c-style string containing only one char considered a string or
>   would you call that construct a char?

Indeed a C-Style string means a `string` i.e. it is quite different from a `char` data type. Since in C language, You don't have a dedicated built-in type to manipulate and represent `string` type like in C++ we have `std::string` hence once has to use character arrays (essentially null terminated) i.e. `char str[SIZE] = "something"` to represent character string type. On the other hand a single character is stored in `char` which is altogether different from `char []`. These two things are not same!

Example,

```
char str[] = "a"; // sizeof(str) will give 2 because presence of extra NULL character
char c = 'a'; // simply a single character
```